# Does Google provide different Index status for HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

Will Google provide different index statuses for HTTP and HTTPS?

Examples:

`http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`

Or it will provide same results for both?

If it doesn't provide the same results, can we configure both HTTP and HTTPS in Google Web Master Tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it'll provide separate index status *if* both versions are set up separately in Webmaster Tools. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/more-precise-index-status-data-for-your.html

Answer (score 2):

Of course it doesn't provide the same results because Google treats these URLs as different URLs. So if you use a canonical tag, then this issue is solved.

Comment: Can you address the Google Webmaster Tools part of the question?